# How to call the AngularJs function during page load

Tags: angularjs

Can anyone tell me how to call the angular js function during page load?
how to call angularjs function in onload?

onload ="angulajs function"??

Comment: Friends don't help friends do things like this. Can you provide some context? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please share what you are trying to do. AngularJS does not function like jquery, you don't code for page events directly.